# Unable to authenticate azure App service and get the data in spfx react solution

Tags: reactjs, api, azure-active-directory, spfx

We are trying to call a web api hosted in azure app service from SPFX react webpart using aadhttpclientfactory.

We are receiving the below error.

Error: Error - Type : interaction_required - Description : AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID <> named 'SharePoint Online Client Extensibility Web Application Principal'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.

Please suggest the process to resolve the above issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For us, we needed to give access to the “SharePoint Online Client Extensibility Web Application Principal” App Registration on our web-hosted API. Follow these steps to do this:

1. Go to the App Registration for your web-hosted API
2. Expose an API > Add a client application
3. Input the client Id for the “SharePoint Online Client Extensibility Web Application Principal” App Registration
4. Select the checkboxes for any permissions

Answer (score 0):

You need to consent to use the application. Go to azure portal->Azure Active Directory->App registrations->find your application->Api permissions->click **Grant admin consent** button(remember to login with the admin account)

[image]

If the permissions does't require admin consent, you can also use [individual user consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#requesting-individual-user-consent) which doesn't need admin permission.